# JJTREE renames #MAINCLASS

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

```
void MainClass() #MAINCLASS:  {} { Some Tokens }
```

JJTREE seems to rename MAINCLASS to ASTMAINCLASS when generating the node, any ideea why this happens? will add more info as requestested

Answer (score 0):

Because `"AST"` is the default value of the `NODE_PREFIX` option.

If you don't want a prefix, try setting the `NODE_PREFIX` option to `""`.

Source: https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html.